# IDW Interpolation map using Python

Tags: python

I need to obtain a color map using interpolation of Longitudinal Conductance records. I have a set of points located along a region and in each point I have Longitudinal Conductance record. This dataset is in google sheet and i would like to import it from google sheet in case the dataset update inside. The link for the data is

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15QIC3R-CqVdHPK1s-aJIMgX8dlt6MmflcZCivpREh1g/edit#gid=1305233270

The area in which this data is located is Phuket island, Thailand area. I think there are shape file provided in this link. However, i do not know which one to use and the way to import it to python. This is the link.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IyhnW9r5i-wH7llww-OjRE9iHGovYNBX?usp=drive_link

Can anyone please help teach me how to use these two data to create map that looks like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ildQf.png)

or this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXS0C.jpg)